# How can access loop arguments in array reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I'm try to acces array items in while using array.reduce. item.ay property is a dynamic. I have to catch in a loop. But i cant access this item. Here my code

```
objectKeys.forEach(ay => {
        let lastArray = this.personalDataset.reduce((a, item, index) => {
          return (
            a + (this.spendingGroups[index].yourRate / 100) * (1 + item.ay)
          );
        }, 0);
        chartArray.push((lastArray - 1) * 100);
      });
      console.log(chartArray);
```

This code return [nan,nan] array. when using reduce without loop and push its all good.

Comment: `1 + item[ay]` perhaps?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `chartArray.push((lastArray - 1) * 100)`? I think you can not subtract 1 of an array. Reduce returns an Array, so you should porbably do something like `chartArray.push((lastArray[0] - 1) * 100)`

Comment: @HasBert _"Reduce returns an Array..."_ - No it doesn't. In this case it's a number

Comment: could you provide sample data and desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use implicit conversion to `Number` by adding plus sign `+`:

```
objectKeys.forEach(ay => {
    let lastArray = this.personalDataset.reduce((a, item, index) => {
      return (
        a + (this.spendingGroups[index].yourRate / 100) * (1 + (+item[ay]))
      );
    }, 0);
    chartArray.push((lastArray - 1) * 100);
});
console.log(chartArray);
```

Comment: @Mert I am glad that it helped to you!:)